# Showing path on google map from json data

Tags: jquery, json, rest, google-maps-api-3

Here i have markers coming in response as Json object and these markers are getting displayed on Google map. Here i want to draw path between these markers but firebug showing error invalid value of (value.Latitude). Here value is my JSON object.

```
var request = {
                    origin:value.Latitude, 
                    destination:value.Longitude,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                };
```

Here's my entire script

```
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
 </script>

 <style type="text/css">
  #map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  position: static;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
}
</style>



<script>
      var directionDisplay;
       var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

     function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.5236, 73.8478);
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false
};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var Source = $("#Source").val();
        var Destination = $("#Destination").val();
        authenticate(Source, Destination);
    });
});

function authenticate(Source,Destination) {
   $('#somediv').empty();

   var table = $('<table/>').appendTo($('#somediv'));
   $.ajax
    ({
      type: 'GET',
        url: 'REST/WebService/GetLogin',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{'Source': Source, 'Destination': Destination },

        error:function()
        {
            alert("unsuccessfull");
        },
        success:function(feeds)
        {   
            alert(feeds.length);

            $.each(feeds, function (index, value) {

               new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(value.Latitude,value.Longitude),
                        map: map,
                        title: "Marker Placing"
              });

                var request = {
                    origin:value.Latitude, 
                    destination:value.Longitude,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                };

               directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    }
               });  
            });
                //alert(feeds.toSource());
        }

     });
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What are the values of `origin:value.Latitude` and `destination:value.Longitude`?  Based on their names and how you are using them to create a google.maps.Marker, the directions request seems incorrect, they need to either be an address string or a google.maps.LatLng object, not just a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`showing error invalid value of (value.Latitude).`

value.Latitude is a single number.  To pass it into a DirectionsService request, it needs to be converted into a google.maps.LatLng object (which takes 2 numeric arguments for its constructor) or a string which is an address that can be geocoded.

[From the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest):

```
origin      | LatLng|string | Location of origin. This can be specified as either a string to be geocoded or a LatLng. Required.
destination | LatLng|string | Location of destination. This can be specified as either a string to be geocoded or a LatLng. Required.
```

Comment: So how can i do it? I am stuck over here, since i was trying some random stuff.

Comment: What are the source and destination coordinates?  I only see one marker/set of coordinates. Create google.maps.LatLng objects with them and pass them into the DirectionsRequest.

Comment: Source and destination coordinates are JSON object in form of latitude and longitude values. Everywhere i am seeing start and end as string. What if i want these to be latitude and longitude values. I am not getting how can i convert these and pass it to google.maps.LatLng()?

Comment: here i am able to convert to var request = { origin:new google.maps.LatLng(value.Latitude,value.Longitude),destination:new google.maps.LatLng(value.Latitude,value.Longitude),travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING };. But values are getting collapsed from json object i want them to be separated somehow?

Comment: What do you mean "values are getting collapsed from json object?  Those are the same location, are you really trying to do that?  If not, you need to make the two locations unique somehow.

Comment: In below code just tell me how can i separate latitude and longitude values output coming after alert {18,17} , i want to separate both values that's only i need                                                               start.push(new google.maps.LatLng(value.Latitude,value.Longitude)); 
alert(start[index]);